# Regex help required, struck with the usage of backslash

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create a Java regex which will return true if there are odd number of backslashes() at the end of a String and false if even.

This is my regular expression

```
    String regex = "^.*[^\\](\\\\)*\\$";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
```

when I compile the code I get following exception

Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 15
^.*([^])(\)*\$

In place of backslash if I use M pattern compiles and works fine

```
    String regex = "^.*" + "[^M]" + "(MM)*M$";
```

I know it is sort of escaping problem but I am not able to figure it out. Following is the whole method

```
    private static void testSpecificRegex() {
    String a = "india\\";
    String b = "india\\\\";
    String c = "india\\\\\\";
    String d = "india\\\\\\\\";

/*  String a = "indiaM";
    String b = "indiaMM";
    String c = "indiaMMM";
    String d = "indiaMMMM";*/

    String regex = "^.*[^\\](\\\\)*\\$";
    //String regex = "^.*" + "[^M]" + "(MM)*M$";
    System.err.println(regex);
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex); // why i need to compile
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(a); 
    System.err.println(matcher.matches());
    matcher = pattern.matcher(b); 
    System.err.println(matcher.matches());
    matcher = pattern.matcher(c); 
    System.err.println(matcher.matches());
    matcher = pattern.matcher(d); 
    System.err.println(matcher.matches());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will do the trick:

`(^|[^\\\\]+)(\\\\\\\\)*$`

explanation:

- it might start with no letters.
- zero is also an even number
- you just force that the string will end with at a multiple of \\. that is. \\ \\\ \\\\

use this site for debugging regex and extra information :
http://regex101.com/

Answer (score 3):

This one works `"^.*[^\\\\](\\\\\\\\)*\\\\$"`. You simply forgot some backslashes.
You can use [this site](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) to test you regexes.
Oh, and you should check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE) to be sure that the `^` and `$` operators are working as you think.
From the link:

> By default these expressions only match at the beginning and the end of the entire input sequence

So if you want to match the beginning and the end of lines, you should add "(?m)" at the beginning of the regex

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negative lookbehind `(?<!..)` to check that there is no backslash before and escape backslashes as Mathieu notices it.

```
 String regex = "(?<!\\\\)(?:\\\\{2})*\\\\$";
```

or the same without lookbehind:

```
String regex = "(?:^|[^\\\\])(?:\\\\{2})*\\\\$";
```

Comment: This doesn't address the even vs odd question.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked here [Stackoverflow Jan2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14390722/java-regex-pattern-unclosed-character-class)

Essentially you have to double escape your escape characters because slash is a java and regex escape character.

This worked for me.

```
String regex = "^.*[^\\\\](\\\\){2,}$";
```

I also added where you could define what is an unreasonable number of slashes. You can decide 2 or more like I did or change it to 3 or 4, etc..

My output using the regex above...

^.*^\{2,}$
false
true
true
true

Cheers!