# java regex double-backslash in character class

Tags: java, regex, backslash, character-class

I need to do the following regex in Java:

Split a string at each comma that's not preceded by a backslash (ie. escaped) and is followed by zero or more whitespaces.

I've been trying this:

```
String str = "Name=Doe\, Jane, Hobby=Skiing, Height=1.70";
String[] parts = str.split("[^\\],\s*");
```

which is the correct syntax in Perl and works there. Not so in Java.

The above already throws an exception during compilation:

```
error: illegal escape character
    String[] parts = str.split("[^\\],\s*");
```

Adding a third and fourth backslash in the character class doesn't help

```
str.split("[^\\\\],\s*");
```

Adding a second backslash to the whitespace allows it to compile,

```
String[] parts = str.split("[^\\],\\s*");
```

but then a runtime `regex.PatternSyntaxException` occurs, stating an `unclosed character class`:

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class
near index 7
[^\],\s*
       ^
```

Clearly there's a backslash missing, and I can't get it in ...
Can anybody tell me how this should be done in Java?

thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `regex` does what you want. You forgot to add two additional `\\`:

```
String[] parts = str.split("[^\\\\],\\s*");
```

Like explained in this question: ([java regex pattern unclosed character class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14390722/java-regex-pattern-unclosed-character-class))

Comment: Ah, yes ... makes sense. Just goes to show that random trial and error is not a good idea ... thanks!

Comment: when should I add double backslash? When I want to split String using "," , I find I should write it like str.split("\\.");  But if I splits String using "/" , I do not have to add double backslash in front of it. Why this happens? Could you help me with that?

Comment: @SHUYULYU The double backslash is used for escaping, so if your regex does contain a backslash you need to escape it otherwise it handles the single backslash wrong because it is a special sign in regex. 
When you use a normal string you can also use the @ sign in front of the string.