# Regex expression for fetching String containing quotes

Tags: java, regex

I am working with regex for fetching string value containing quotes. In below example I want to get value summary key as "Here is "summary". Currently I am getting only "Here is " as output of below program. I want to escape all double quotes those comes in-between first and final double quote.

```
    String in = "summary = \"Here is \"summary\"";  

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("'(.*?)'|\"(.*?)[^\\\"]+\"");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(in);

    while(m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Use greedy matching: `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("'(.*)'|\"(.*)\"");`

Comment: does it correct input while contains three `\"` ?

Comment: Greedy works fine as well. Thanks Wiktor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this one:

```
/\\["']((?:[^"\\]|\\.)*)\\["']/
```

Demo : https://regex101.com/r/033EKx/1

Remember: When trying to build regex by `"` , `\` should change to `\\` and other special characters (`"` and `'`)

```
rStr = "/\\\\[\"\']((?:[^\"\\\\]|\\\\.)*)\\\\[\"\']/" ;
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed a bit to fit my solution "((?:[^"\\]|\\.)*)"

Comment: Getting exception in Java Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 22
["']((?:[^"\]|\.)*)["']

Comment: Problem is in converting string regex pattern with " string definer, some \ are missed. what is your string @AAjit

Comment: About un-closed character class: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21816788/unclosed-character-class-error) and [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14390722/java-regex-pattern-unclosed-character-class) @AAjit