# String Split Error

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I'm trying to split each element of a JavaRDD by space except the part in quotes and []. I'm using the following code for the purpose

```
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("LogAnalyzer");
            JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
            JavaRDD<String[]> logRdd = sc.textFile(logPath).map(new Function<String, String[]>() {
                  public String[] call(String s) { 
                  return s.split("\\s+(?![^\\\\[]*\\\\])(?=(?:[^\\\"]*\\\"[^\\\"]*\\\")*[^\\\"]*$)"); 
               }
            });
            for(String[] arr : logRdd.take(10)) {
              for(String s : arr) {
                  System.out.print("| "+s+" |");
                }
              System.out.println("-------------------");
            }
            sc.close();
```

But I get this error on run time

```
18/06/05 01:07:02 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 49
\\s+(?![^\\[]*\\])(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)
                                             ^
```

I don't get this when I use this in a simple java file

```
String[] splitted = s.split("\\s+(?![^\\[]*\\])(?=(?:[^\\\"]*\\\"[^\\\"]*\\\")*[^\\\"]*$)");
```

Do I need to do something else in Spark? Please let me know if any more information is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two extra `\\` in

```
public String[] call(String s) { return s.split("\\s+(?![^\\\\[]*\\\\])(?=(?:[^\\\"]*\\\"[^\\\"]*\\\")*[^\\\"]*$)"); }
```

which should be

```
public String[] call(String s) { return s.split("\\s+(?![^\\[]*\\])(?=(?:[^\\\"]*\\\"[^\\\"]*\\\")*[^\\\"]*$)"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

I read in another topic that, for regex, in order to include ], you need to add additional ] at the end. like this :

```
    [^\"]]*$)");
```

I duplicated your code and I was getting " Unclosed character class" error from IDE. After the modification, there was no problem. Although I don't know if it will produce the regex result you wanted.

Comment: You can find more information in this topic about "Unclosed character class": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14390722/java-regex-pattern-unclosed-character-class